# Adding a marker zooms map out fully when using Gmaps G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP with earth plugin

Tags: google-maps-api-2, google-earth-plugin

`Gmap.addoverlay()` causes map to zoom out if you've called `getEarthInstance()`.

Using ge plugin 6.2.1.6014, Chrome/Mac OSX and {Firefox,Chrome}/Windows Vista Home Premium (Cross-posted on [Google Earth API issues](https://web.archive.org/web/20160103051231/https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=769)). See the test code [here](https://www.heywhatsthat.com/hacks/ge62bug.html).

Shortly after the second marker appears, the maps zooms out, even though noone asked it to.
By putting an `alert()` in that callback and extending the `timeout()` interval, I'm pretty sure it's the `addOverlay()`, not the `getEarthInstance()`, where the problem occurs.

To immunize my code, I tried the commented code in the callback, but it's apparently too late by then.

So, is there any way to determine the version of the plug-in without calling `getEarthInstance()`?  Perhaps some hacking with `google.load`?  Without a clean way to detect the version of the plug-in, I'd have to disable the `G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP` as long as any of this version of the plug-in remain installed out there, which, I'm thinking, is pretty much forever?

I'm calling `getEarthInstance()` because I want to enable a few layers and set a click listener on the globe. Is it possible to do either of those things without `getEarthInstance()`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used v2 of the Maps API extensively, so maybe this is a long-known behavior, but this does appear to be a bug. I suggest filing it on the [Maps API v2 issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20API%20v2%20-%20Regression), as the plugin itself (or the plugin API) can't really do anything to change the view of the map.

Please note that v2 of the API has been deprecated (since May 2010!), so they are only fixing regressions. Also, you should really consider switching to v3 of the API; there's even a handy [library for Earth API integration](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/docs/reference.html).

In the meantime, there are a few approaches that might help:

1. Is there a reason that you're checking the version number of the
   plugin? There have been some additions to the API in recent
   releases, but I'm not sure what in 6.2 would be a deal-breaker. The
   plugin has used the same auto-updater as Google Earth for some time
   now, so the vast majority of users are on the latest version of the
   plugin anyway. There are a handful of holdouts on 5.x and 6.0 for
   specific reasons, but there really aren't very many. For almost
   everyone that visits your site, the isSupported() check should be
   sufficient, and if it isn't, they have probably purposefully opted
   out and know why things aren't working.
2. Since you're loading the earth Javascript library anyway, you can
   consider just loading an instance of the plugin without involving
   the API. [google.earth.createInstance](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#a70288485024d8129dd1c290fb2e5553b) will help you out there
   (you can use a hidden html element if that matters, just make sure
   to detach it and let it be garbage collected when you're finished).
   There is some overhead in starting up a plugin instance and then
   discarding it, but it's pretty minor over just starting it, which
   you're already doing here. The next plugin instance will also be
   created more quickly when the view is switched to 3D.

Comment: Thanks! `google.earth.createInstance()` is just what I needed to check for the bug without getting hit by it. I'll post some code in another answer in case anyone gets bitten by the same bug.

As to checking the version number, I wasn't clear enough in my post: the bad behavior cropped up in a [long-running maps v2 app](http://wisp.heywhatsthat.com) that started breaking as users upgraded (or were auto-upgraded) to the current GE.  The bug does not seem to hit, for example, when I run the test code on an XP machine at GE version 6.1.0.5001.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who's been hit by this bug, thanks to the suggestion in the answer by Mr. Kenny, here's some code to check the plug-in version without falling victim to the bug we're trying to avoid:

```
function enable_geplugin(map, div, callback) {
  if (!google.earth.isSupported())
    return;

  var earth_div = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(earth_div);
  earth_div.style.height  = '1px';
  earth_div.style.width   = '1px';

  google.earth.createInstance(
    earth_div,
    function(instance) {
      if (!instance.getPluginVersion().match(/^6\.2\./)) {
        map.addMapType(G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP);
        if (callback)
          map.getEarthInstance(callback);
        }
      earth_div.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.removeChild(earth_div);
    },
    function(errorCode) {
        // do this so user can click on map type "Earth" and see the download instructions
      map.addMapType(G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP);
      earth_div.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.removeChild(earth_div);
    }
  );
}
```

Used, for example, [here](http://www.heywhatsthat.com/hacks/ge62bug-1.html).

(On OSX/Chrome, the `document.body.removeChild(earth_div)` generates an *Uncaught ReferenceError: NPObject deleted*, but that's the least of my worries.)

So we can now effectively disable G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP for bad plug-in releases, but I still hope someone working on the plug-in fixes the bug itself.